# Drawing a sawtooth waveform ontop of a sine wave PGF plots

Tags: pgfplots

I have a fully rectified sinusoidal wave that I am trying to place a sawtooth wave form on top of as the image bellow,

[image]

I originally had a messy solution but it was not very good, I have a tex sine wave im trying to place it on bellow.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    domain=0:1.5*360,
    samples=4*360,
    xtick=\empty,
    width=10cm, height=4cm,
    ymin=0,
    enlarge x limits=false
]
\addplot [densely dashed] {abs(sin(x))};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Creating such a plot looks easy enough given either a data file or formula for the sawtooth. Could you explain where you issue is, exactly?

Comment: Yeh well thats my question, I can plot a sawtooth by drawing lines but what formula would I use..this is where im at.. \addplot [very thick] {0.5-atan(cot((pi*x)/2))};

Comment: well throwing in some magic numbers i have a solution for it,\addplot [very thick] {0.91+0.001*atan(cot(95+ ((0.63*pi*x)/2)))};

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `1 - 1/(3*180)*mod(x+90,180)` to plot a sawtooth wave. `mod(x,180)` repeats every `180` units, `1/(3*180)` scales the values (`1/180` would result in a sawtooth wave running from `0` to `1`).

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    domain=0:1.5*360,
    samples=4*360,
    xtick=\empty,
    width=10cm, height=4cm,
    ymin=0,
    enlarge x limits=false
]
\addplot [densely dashed] {abs(sin(x))};
\addplot [very thick] {1-1/(3*180)*mod(x+90,180)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

This is one possible solution where `foreach` loop is used with a line approximation with sawtooth waveform.

if  one wants the line to touch the curve without penetrating into the sine wave then remove the vertical line and change `\arch` definition to 60

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\def\arch{90}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    domain=0:1.5*360,
    samples=360,
    xtick={0,90,180,270,360,450,540},
    width=10cm, height=5cm,
    ymin=0, ymax=1.5, xmin=0,
    enlarge x limits=false
]
\addplot [densely dashed] {abs(sin(x))};
% draw the rectified line approximation via foreach skill
\foreach \i/\j in {-1/0,1/2,3/4}{
\addplot [thick,domain=\i*90:{\j*90+\arch}] 
{1-0.001*(x-\i*90)};
\addplot[thick] coordinates{(\i*90,1)(\i*90,{1-0.001*(\j*90+\arch-\i*90)})}; % remove this line if the vertical line is undesired  and change arch to 90
}
\node[coordinate, pin =above:{\parbox{2cm}{\tiny Voltage Simplified by Approximation}}] at (axis cs: 180,0.9) {};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```